# Out scope variable of onPageFinished

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm trying to get a String outside onPageFinished. Is it possible?

This script shows what I'm trying to do:

```
    WebView webview;
    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    public String test;

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
           public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                test=IsLoggedIn();
            }
        });

    String a = test;
```

Comment: Make your variable global at declaration part.

Comment: Is it even possible to declare a global variable in android? @PiyushGupta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added this line at the start of the Activity to create a global variable:

```
   private String test;

    public String test() {
        return test;
    }
```

Thanks for Piyush Gupta for redacting me to search it.